# Looping over python script with different date inputs

Tags: bash

I have a python script that has to be executed with start and end dates. I want to execute this file for each day in the year 2012, so I thought a while-loop inside a bash script would do the job but my bash-skills are not sufficient.

This is what I tried:

```
day_start = 2012-01-01

while [ "$day_start" != 2013-01-01 ] ; 
do
    day_end =$(date -I -d "$day_start + 1 day")
    python script.py --since ="$day_start" --until = "$day_end" ;
    day_start =$(date -I -d "$day_start + 1 day")
    echo $day_start
done
```

The error message I get is that python does not seem to like the "$bash-variable" input. Also, I thought this was the way to +1 for days inside bash, but I get an error for day_end and day_start as well. Can somebody help me out here? (Sorry if this is probably pretty basic!)

Comment: My suggestion when debugging such problems is to remove all code which does not contribute to the problem, i.e. create a minimal test case (see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man bash` says:

> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form
>
> ```
> name=[value]
> ```

Therefore you need to replace `day_start = 2012-01-01` by `day_start=2012-01-01`, similarly for the other two assignments.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to do this would probably be to enclose the python script's contents in a while loop that would iterate over every day in 2012, and do away with the requirement to use bash at all.

If your script's contents were:

```
year, month, day = sys.argv[1].split('-')
print(datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day)).strftime('%d'))
```

It would become:

```
date = datetime.date(2012, 1, 1)
while date.year != 2013:
    print(date.strftime('%d'))
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```